# Ruby (Rack) application could not be started Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, rvm, ubuntu-10.04, passenger

I've been struggling with this for a bit longer than I should. I am using RVM and Apache and this is the error I am getting after deploying my Rails 3 app. Is there something I am missing?!

the full error states the following:

Ruby (Rack) application could not be started
A source file that the application requires, is missing.

It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.

A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.

Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

Error message:
no such file to load -- bundler/setup

Exception class:
LoadError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Passenger is using a different Ruby than RVM probably the system Ruby.  You'll need to either install Passenger manually (using your Ruby of choice with RVM) and remove the system Ruby or install bundler with the system Ruby.

Comment: I am having no luck with that.. When I run this command... passenger-install-apache2-module... Passenger is telling me...Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old. Please update them first by running 'rvm get head && rvm reload && rvm repair all'...However, after running this rvm command still nothing

Comment: How many Ruby versions do you have installed?  Try to determine which Ruby is being used by passenger and which Ruby you're using in your development environment.  Then make sure bundler is installed for the Ruby that passenger is using.  That should fix it.  Try this first because this will verify that the issue is that you're using two different versions of Ruby.  Then, once you verify this you can resolve the issue.

Comment: That was it. What I ended up doing was removing the original ruby 1.8.7 and RVM and reinstalling RVM. This seemed to do the trick. Thank you.

Comment: @drnewman : I know this is a very old thread, but I'm running into the same issue and wondered how do you determine which Ruby is being used by passenger and which Ruby I'm using in my development environment? Thanks